# Loading each cell with different data Collection View in IOS

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to iOS app development.I am stuck here with a problem.I have a collection view.I want to load each cell of that collection view with different widgets,i.e in the first cell i have a table view with each cell having an image,2nd cell should be another table view with an imageview,2 labels,etc,3 cell should be having another design.can i do that?

Comment: I'd consider possibly using sections and then having each section do what you want (e.g. first section is all cells having an image, second section is all cells having an image + 2 labels, etc.).

Then you can keep the design simpler and not embed table views into collection views, and change the cell class you use based on the section the cell is in.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can do that, it sort of defeats the purpose of the collection view as a collectionview should be a set of similar views.

But it can be done if you implement cellForItemAtIndexPath and use a case statement for laying out the subviews depending on the item

Comment: can u explain how i can do that?all the tables are custom tables too.kindly help..thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dataSource method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and run a `switch` case on each `indexPath.item`. Set your unique views for each item and return the cell.

```
UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier atIndexPath:indexPath];

switch (indexPath.item) {
    case 0:
        //add unique views
    break;
    case 1:
        //add unique views
    break;
    case 2:
        //add unique views
    break;
    default:
    break;

    return cell;
}
```